# How does MATLAB determine validity of expression / check whether parentheses are balanced?

Tags: matlab, validation

If you try to run code in which a parenthesis is missing (`(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{` or `}`), the script or function throws an error:

> Error: File: XXX.m Line: 1337 Column: 42
>
> Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.

It seems to do this before executing. I have my editor set to 'Pause on Errors', but contrary to other errors (such as referring to a variable that doesn't exist), it doesn't "jump" to the line with the error.

That got me wondering. At first I thought, MATLAB might count all of the types of parentheses, and check whether there are as many opening ones as there are closing ones of a particular type. That, however, doesn't seem to be the case as:

- The error identifies the correct line and column. A procedure as described above wouldn't be able to do that - as it looks at parentheses *at file level*, rather than as pairs.
- This would include parentheses used in strings, which can of course be unbalanced.

My question: **How does MATLAB check whether parentheses are balanced** or, more general, **how does MATLAB determine validity of expression**?

Comment: Any answers, unless provided by someone who wrote the MATLAB application, would likely be pure speculation, therefore this question is off topic as "primarily opinion based". You can see, by the way the MATLAB editor underlines parenthesis issues as you write code, that it clearly knows where they happen without having to compile.

Comment: MATLAB parses the code before it starts executing it. This means that all of the syntax must be correct, not just having the right number of brackets. You should read up on parsing. It's a very interesting topic, with lots of stuff to learn.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB basically runs [`checkcode`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html) on the fly, generating those red wiggles when you type, and indeed those errors whenever you try to run code with unbalanced parentheses and/or square/curly brackets. You can see what `checkcode()` does, by simply typing `edit checkcode` in your command window. I won't paste its code here, since it's probably proprietary, but the help file says:

> To force Code Analyzer to ignore a line of code, use `%#ok` at the end of the
>   line. This tag can be followed by comments.  For example:
>
> ```
> unsuppressed1 = 10   % This line will get caught
> suppressed2 = 20     %#ok  These next two lines will not get caught
> suppressed3 = 30     %#ok
> ```

so its Code Analyzer (sic) does the checks. Probably it runs some regex-like checks per line.

For a more detailed answer one should contact The MathWorks directly, as the rest is mostly closed-source.